# vb.net timeadding from two textbox

Tags: vb.net

Please help me first before giving me a bad feedback.

I need to add two time from text box. But when I'm adding it only the minute was adding and not the hours.

```
Dim dt As DateTime = TxtDTEAP.Text
Dim wt As DateTime = TxtWTEAP.Text
Dim totalspan As New TimeSpan
Dim result As New DateTime

result = dt.AddMinutes(wt.Minute)

Me.TxtTRTEAP.Text = result
```

For example, the `txtWTEAP.Text = 1:30` and `txtDTEAP.Text = 2:50` the result should be `4:20` but the result showing on this code is `1:20` only.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why would you be surprised that only the minutes are being added when explicitly get the `Minutes` property and call `AddMinutes`? Why would you expect your code to do something different to what you have expressly told it to do?

Comment: First things first, why use `TextBoxes` in the first place?  Why not use `DateTimePickers`?  You can configure them to show only the time and then you can use `myDateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay` to get a time entered as a `TimeSpan`.  You can then simply add the two values using the standard addition operator, i.e. `+`, to get a total time as a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: `Dim wt As DateTime = TxtWTEAP.Text`. Really? Please use `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict On`. Another, Don't use `Textboxes` for `dates` and `time` data. Instead use `DateTimePicker` it's easy to use and it may be what you need. there are many tutorials for this. Just search the internet.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your wonderful feedback about my post. I hate to say this but you guys didn't help me a bit. Why I ask this if I'm going to use DateTimePicker? Why do people comment on the wrong part but not answering the real question. If you don't know the answer just be kind and search another question that you know how to answer! THANK YOU!

Comment: No one is commenting on the wrong part. The most appropriate way to do this is to use a `DateTimePicker`. If someone doesn't know that and are using `TextBoxes` because they don't know any better and we don't point it out then we are doing them a disservice. If someone does know this and they fail to specify in their question that they know it but that they must use `TextBoxes` for some specific reason then it is the person posting the question who has done the wrong thing by failing to provide ALL the relevant information. We only know what you tell us so tell us EVERYTHING that matters.

Comment: Regardless of that, if you care to read what's been provided then you already have the information you need. I told you why you're only seeing minutes added and I also told you that what you should be doing is simply adding two `TimeSpan` values`. That's all you need if you apply some thought to the problem. The only extra thing you need to do is get two `TimeSpans` from your `TextBoxes`. You can do that by parsing the `Text` directly to type `TimeSpan` or you can get the `TimeOfDay` (which I also already mentioned) from the `DateTimes` you already have. Concentrate on what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I did this because I need to know if there's any better solution if we're going to use `TextBox` to compute time. I know I'm a newbie in this and I'm still learning. From what you said, you only eager me to learn it and solve this by my self and not asking in this site anything. We beginners is not pro like you that's why we find a better solution by asking on this site. Thanks for your time by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Split the strings in the TextBoxes into an array. The first element will contain the hours and the second element will contain the minutes. The c following the split character tells the compiler this is a char not a string.
2. Use the constructor of the TimeSpan structure to create TimeSpans. The constructor takes 3 arguments, Hours as Integer, Minutes as Integer and Seconds as Integer.
3. Finally, we can do the addition.
4. Then display the result using .ToString with a format string. The \ is and escape character so it doesn't think the : is something else.

```vb
 Private Sub GetTotalTime()
            Dim parseTime1() As String = TxtDTEAP.Text.Split(":"c)
            Dim parseTime2() As String = TxtWTEAP.Text.Split(":"c)
            Dim dt As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(CInt(parseTime1(0)), CInt(parseTime1(1)), 0)
            Dim wt As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(CInt(parseTime2(0)), CInt(parseTime2(1)), 0)
            Dim result As TimeSpan = dt + wt
            TxtTRTEAP.Text = result.ToString("h\:mm")
    End Sub
```